# Polygon style settings not working KML google maps api

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

I'm using the javascript API for Google Maps and uploaded a kml.  It's picking up the .kml fine, but the polygon style isn't pulling in correctly.  I've got 4 polygons each with different colors and this is what it renders as:

[image: Rendering]

Here is the .kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="root_doc">
    <Schema name="LandOwnership" id="LandOwnership">
      <SimpleField name="OWNER" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="AGENCY" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="ADMIN" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="DESIG" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="STATE_LGD" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="UT_LGD" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="NATL_LGD" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="EDIT_DATE" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="LABEL_FEDE" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="LABEL_STAT" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="GIS_ACRES" type="float"/>
      <SimpleField name="COUNTY" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="SHAPE_Leng" type="float"/>
      <SimpleField name="SHAPE_Area" type="float"/>
    </Schema>
    <Folder>
      <name>LandOwnership</name>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#LandOwnership">
            <SimpleData name="OWNER">Federal</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="AGENCY">BLM</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ADMIN">BLM</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="DESIG">N/A</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="STATE_LGD">Bureau of Land Management</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="UT_LGD">Bureau of Land Management (BLM)</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="NATL_LGD">Bureau of Land Management (BLM)</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="EDIT_DATE">2008/10/01</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="GIS_ACRES">81.45050049000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="COUNTY">CACHE</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Leng">2445.42598229000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Area">329618.47060000000</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                  -114.0490723,42.0003251,0
                  -114.0710449,37.0025527,0
                  -112.6757812,37.0025527,0
                  -112.6538086,42.008489,0
                  -114.0490723,42.0003251,0
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
        <styleUrl>#federal</styleUrl>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#LandOwnership">
            <SimpleData name="OWNER">State</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="AGENCY">DNR</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ADMIN">UDWR</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="DESIG">Wildlife Reserve/Management Area</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="STATE_LGD">State Wildlife Reserve/Management Area</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="UT_LGD">State Wildlife Reserve/Management Area</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="NATL_LGD">State, County, City; Wildlife, Park and Outdoor Recreation Areas</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="EDIT_DATE">2008/10/01</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="GIS_ACRES">308.72662354000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="COUNTY">CACHE</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Leng">6565.50929155000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Area">1249372.33890000009</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                -112.6538086,42.008489,0
                -112.6757812,37.0025527,0
                -111.159668,37.0288694,0
                -111.1486816,42.008489,0
                -112.6538086,42.008489,0
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
        <styleUrl>#state</styleUrl>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#LandOwnership">
            <SimpleData name="OWNER">Tribal</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="AGENCY">Tribal</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ADMIN">Tribal</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="DESIG">Indian Reservation</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="STATE_LGD">Tribal Lands</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="UT_LGD">Indian Reservation (IR)</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="NATL_LGD">Indian Reservation (IR)</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="EDIT_DATE">2008/10/01</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="LABEL_FEDE">Goshute Tribal Lands</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="GIS_ACRES">42453.76562500000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="COUNTY">JUAB</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Leng">119974.20068400000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Area">171804294.54600000381</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                -111.159668,37.0288694,0
                -109.083252,37.0200982,0
                -109.0612793,39.2832939,0
                -111.1376953,39.291797,0
                -111.159668,37.0288694,0
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
        <styleUrl>#tribal</styleUrl>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#LandOwnership">
            <SimpleData name="OWNER">Private</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="AGENCY">Private</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ADMIN">Private</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="DESIG">N/A</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="STATE_LGD">Private</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="UT_LGD">Private</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="NATL_LGD">Private</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="EDIT_DATE">2008/10/01</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="GIS_ACRES">80.33841705000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="COUNTY">JUAB</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Leng">2427.86686739000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SHAPE_Area">325118.03909999999</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                -111.1486816,41.0047754,0
                -111.1376953,39.291797,0
                -109.0612793,39.2832939,0
                -109.0393066,40.996484,0
                -111.1486816,41.0047754,0
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
        <styleUrl>#private</styleUrl>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Style id="federal">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>4DFF0000</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>FF0000</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="state">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>4DFFF500</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>FFF500</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="tribal">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>4DFF7E00</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>FF7E00</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="private">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>4D0000FF</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>0000FF</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Google Maps API does not support the ExtendedData in KML/KMZ files you need to use google earth or generate your kml to json [jquery] and apply colour in that approach. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578141/accessing-extendeddata-information-via-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: You might get a little further with using https://earth.google.com/web/@0,7.658201,0a,22251752d,35y,0h,0t,0r/data=CgAoAQ and signing in to view your mymap kmls

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, removing the ExtendedData seems to fix the LineStyle problem, but the fill is still missing.

Answer (score 3):

Your PolyStyle colors need eight characters, not six.

KML colors are written like this:

```
<color>AABBGGRR</color>
```

- **AA** = Alpha/Opacity
- **BB** = Blue
- **GG** = Green
- **RR** = Red

Note that the BGR ordering is backwards from the traditional RGB.

This is different from HTML colors which are written with only six characters, like this:

```
#RRGGBB
```

Try adding "FF" (fully opaque, no transparency) to the beginning of each PolyStyle color, and you'll see the polygons are filled with color when viewed in Earth. That should work in Maps too.

Comment: This is helpful.  I added FF to the Polystyle colors (the LineStyle colors were already 8 digits), however, and it didn't change anything (still no fill).  Geojson is working, though, so I might switch to that.

Comment: Hmm... sorry it's not working yet.  Unlikely to be the issue, but one other KML schema issue is that your styleUrl tags should come before ExtendedData.  See the KML reference for correct tag order: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#placemark

Another thing to check is that you're actually getting the new file... not a cached copy of the old one. Try changing the filename to confirm?